# Check whether file downloaded successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to check whether the file (.pdf as an example) downloaded successfully.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public FilePathResult Index()
    {
        return File("path/to/file", "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

I was able to find this solution:

```
public class CheckedFileStreamResult : FileStreamResult
{
    public CheckedFileStreamResult(FileStream stream, string contentType)
    :base(stream, contentType)
    {
        DownloadCompleted = false;
    }

    public bool DownloadCompleted { get; set; }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        var outputStream = response.OutputStream;
        using (FileStream)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
            var count = FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
            while(count != 0 && response.IsClientConnected)
            {                 
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                count = FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
            }
            DownloadCompleted = response.IsClientConnected;
        }
    }

    private const int _bufferSize = 0x1000;
}
```

I don't understand how can I check **DownloadCompleted** flag within **OnResultExecuted** handler. The action method returns **FilePathResult**. Please guide me how can I check **DownloadCompleted** flag within **OnResultExecuted** handler. Do I need a typecast?

Comment: Are you expecting this to run on the server or the client?

Comment: I'm trying to run this on the server.